# How to obtain "UTC at Midnight" Timestamp with java.time.Instant and ChronoUnit

Tags: json, scala, datetime, timestamp

How to obtain UTC at Midnight Timestamp with java.time.Instant and ChronoUnit?

I am trying to get UTC at Midnight Timestamp in format. For example, if today were Feb 10 2017, then correct date: Fri Feb 10 00:00:00 UTC 2017 which is equal to timestamp: 1486684800000 (I want for current date and time).

I tried

```
Instant.now
Instant.now.getEpochSecond to pass in JSON it end up in error
```

Error :

```
"statusCode":400,"titleMessage":"Value not allowed","userMessage":"The date with time stamp 2,022 is not in UTC at midnight
```

Please suggest a solution

Comment: Is that so?? *`time stamp 2,022`* sounds like you accidentally passed the current year in JSON, but the code you showed doesn’t do that.

Comment: Do you want a date of your choice, for example Feb 10 2017, or do you want today in UTC? Also do you need seconds or milliseconds since the epoch? (The example value you mention, 1486684800000, is milliseconds, but your code gives seconds.)

Comment: In Java syntax: `LocalDate.of(2017, Month.FEBRUARY, 10).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond()`. Gives 1 486 684 800.

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you.
I want for current date and time.

Comment: In that case use `LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` instead of `LocalDate.of(2017, Month.FEBRUARY, 10)` (or pass the time zone of your choice to `LocalDate.now()`).

Comment: Under the linked original questions avoid answers using `Date` or `Calendar`. Use the ones that use java.time, which are most of them. For UTC time prefer `OffsetDateTime` over `ZonedDateTime` (used in one answer where it was needed because of the time zone). Your question has been asked and answered with variations before, so you can search to find even more.

Comment: Someone upvoted this unclear and apparently poorly researched question. Opinions on question quality differ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Truncate

You can [lop off](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) the less significant parts of a date-time value.

In Java syntax:

```
Instant
.now()
.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS )
.toEpochMilli()
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution

I just added .toEpochMilli it worked perfectly.

import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS ).toEpochMilli